# How do I make my Sticky NavBar Scroll Animate properly?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to create a sticky navigation bar that animates(gets smaller) when scrolling. I followed a video on youtube on creating it but it doesn't seem to be working for me every time I try to input the javascript.

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if (window).scrollTop(); {
    $('nav').addClass('black');
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('black');
  }
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@700&display=swap');
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

nav.black {
  background: rgba (0, 0, 0, 8);
}

nav .logo {
  float: left;
}

nav .logo img {
  height: 80px;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

nav .logo a {
  position: fixed;
  padding-top: 25px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

nav ul {
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: 550;
}

nav ul li a {
  line-height: 80px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
}

section.sec1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(./traffic.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

section.sec2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(./traffic.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

section.content {
  padding: 100px;
}

section.content h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 2em;
}

section.content p {
  margin: 20px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Testing Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="maint.css">

</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="trafficlight.png" style="width: 80px;">
      <a href="#">WebSite Name</a>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="about.html">First</a></li>
      <li><a href="packages.html">Packages</a></li>
      <li><a href="classes.html">Classses</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="links.html">Links</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <section class="sec1"></section>
  <section class="content">
    <h1>LoremIpsumLorem<br></h1>
    <p>LoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsum <b>LoremIpsum</b></p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.<br> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy <u>Lorem Ipsum</u> and <u>Lorem Ipsum</u>.<br> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.<br> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.<br>
      <b>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</b></p>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So. A couple of things to note:

1. The js line with `if(window).scrollTop();{` has two syntax issues:

   - Parenthesis should wrap around the WHOLE statement that you are concerned with verifying.
   - You are terminating the statement BEFORE you open your if statements body.
2. It is generally a best practice to wait until the html document has loaded, before attempting to set up any listeners.

Here's the JS that I propose for your case (filler css added to highlight):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    console.log("scroll position: ", $(document).scrollTop());
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 0) {
      $("nav").addClass("black");
    } else {
      $("nav").removeClass("black");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.black {
  background-color: green;
}

body,
section {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="trafficlight.png" style="width: 80px;">
    <a href="#">WebSite Name</a>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="about.html">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="packages.html">Packages</a></li>
    <li><a href="classes.html">Classses</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="links.html">Links</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<section class="sec1"></section>
<section class="content">
  <h1>LoremIpsumLorem<br></h1>
  <p>LoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsum <b>LoremIpsum</b></p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.<br> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy <u>Lorem Ipsum</u> and <u>Lorem Ipsum</u>.<br> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.<br> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.<br>
    <b>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</b></p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy <u>Lorem Ipsum</u> and <u>Lorem Ipsum</u>.<br> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.<br> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.<br>
    <b>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</b></p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy <u>Lorem Ipsum</u> and <u>Lorem Ipsum</u>.<br> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.<br> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.<br>
    <b>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</b></p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy <u>Lorem Ipsum</u> and <u>Lorem Ipsum</u>.<br> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.<br> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.<br>
    <b>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</b></p>
</section>
```